# JSF to receive POST parameters

Tags: post, jsf-2

Today I'm using a servlet to receive a POST from a HTML page and then redirecting to my JSF page.

This is my actual Servlet:

```
   public class CommInServlet extends HttpServlet {

   private String reportKey;

      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
         req.getSession(true).setAttribute("reportKey", req.getParameter("reportkey"));
         req.getRequestDispatcher("main.xhtml").forward(req, resp);
       }

    }
```

HTML post page:

```
<html>
<head />
<body>
<form action="Filtro" method="post">
<input type="text" size="120" name="reportkey" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
<input type="submit" value="doPost" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to post directly to my JSF page (ManagedBean)? How?
I want to replace the Servlet for something... better.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sure you can. Most JSF requests are `POST`s anyway, so if you use the path to the JSF page you're intending to handle the `POST` request, you can then get the parameter within a managed bean that is backed by that page OR get the parameter within the page itself.

Within a managed bean:

```
     @PostConstruct
      public void initMyBean(){
      /**This map contains all the params you submitted from the html form */
      Map<String,String> requestParams = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
      requestParams.get("reportKey");
                       }
```

**OR**
within the managed bean have

```
     @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.reportKey}")
     String reportKey;
     //getter and setter of course!
```

The method you've annotated with `@PostConstruct` will be executed after the managed bean has been instantiated. The above will give you access within your managed bean.

If you need the value within your page first however, you can have this in your page (preferably at the top)

```
     <f:metadata>
      <f:viewParam name="reportKey" value="#{backingBean.reportKey}" required="true"/>
     </f:metadata>
```

Notice how you can perform validations on the parameter from within your view. Pretty cool feature.

Just be sure and set your html form `action` attribute to the path of the JSF view.

Comment: On a viewParam, what does required="true" mean?

Comment: @Erick `required="true"` ensures that the parameter supplied is not null