# getting post parameters from another website in jsf?

Tags: jsf, post

I am developing an application with jsf/ejb that needs to get redirected from another website with post method and I should receive some parameters within that redirection.

Any guidance please?

Comment: What should the response be? The answer depends on that.

Comment: @BalusC : I should get some parameters within post method. imagine there is another html page form that it's post action attribute is my website url and the sender form has some attributes that i should get them.

Comment: I didn't ask for that. That part was already clear from the question. You however only described how the HTTP request looks like. I just asked what the HTTP response should look like. What exactly do you need to return after processing such a request? A whole HTML page? Or just a specific HTTP status code? Or a HTTP redirect to a specific (JSF) page? Or a specific message in plaintext? Or some JSON? Etc. Depending on that I can decide whether JSF is the right tool for the job or not and/or propose the right solution and/or a hack/workaround using JSF.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF to receive POST parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750794/jsf-to-receive-post-parameters)