# Receive a POST request from thirdy-party site using JSF/Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

[image]

Hi,

I've a scenario like in picture.
My problem is in STEP 2: the service provider returns to User's browser a form that onloads submits itselfs to Identity Provide enpoint (on the picture the scenario is a little bit different, because SP returns a redirect response, so the user agent will do a Get request do IP's endpoint).

On Identity Provider I'm using JSF + Primefaces.

I don't know how to retreive posted parameters that come from the form created by the Service Provider.
Is it possible to use the backend functionalities provided by Primefaces ecosystem to retreive values that come from a form rendered by the SP (from another domain)?

I think that Primeface's application lifecycle will broke this mechanism, isn't it?
How can I resolve this problem keeping the adoption of Primefaces/JSF?

Thanks.

Comment: Removed all other comments since now I read the picture is not in line with what actually happens... Hmmmm.... So you do not use a 'standard' or are you using the SSO-SP-POST-POST profile? And who 'defines' the technical things here. You or the SP? If you use a SAML2 compliant solution on both the SP and IdP, change to the profile of which you posted the image

Comment: Btw, you **think** it will break things... Did you try with a simple static page simulating the SP? From reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750794/jsf-to-receive-post-parameters, it should just work...

Comment: @Kukeltje I'm using SAML2 with POST binding (instead of redirect, like in picture).
I'm the Identity Provider.

Comment: Then I'd  either **try** if it just works or tell the SP to use the redirect profile before looking for workarounds. And please change the image to match the correct flow. Shouls not be to difficult